GREP regex to match all "è" at the end of words in a Indesign document and replace with "é"
I'm in trouble with a task in InDesign.
I have a document (in Italian) where I have many occurrencis of words like: nè, sè, benchè, perchè and so on, with grave accent. All these needs to be turned into né, sé, benché, perché, with acute accent. Since there are a lot of words like those in this document, I'm looking for a way to turn any è into é, automatically conditionally with GREP. In Italian, the isolated letter e with grave accent è is a verbal voice, so, I would need a regex to avoid to replace è with é when this character is isolated without only spaces around.
Do you have any suggestion for this? Thanks in advance.

Try this in GREP "Find/Change to":
Find:
\l+\Kè(?=[\h.!?,:;])
Change to:
é
This will find the character è if it is at the end of a word and is followed by one of these: a space,., !, ?, ,, : or ; (but not the isolated character).
Please test it extensively before you choose "Change All".

and if the word containing the è is the last of a line without nothing after, i.e. in a line of poem like this: ''e ti dico che perchè''

You may leave the "follow" part in the expression away, so just \l+\Kè will also suffice and it will find the character if at the end the word which is at the end of the line.

While simpler solutions exist, I find the below expression most intuitive. I use this basic pattern in all kinds of situations.
(?<!\s)è(?!\s)



GREP
description




(?<!
begin negative look-behind


\s
match any whitespace (including line breaks)


)
end negative look-behind


è
the character you want to change


(?!
begin negative look-ahead


\s
match any whitespace (including line breaks)


)
end negative look-ahead



